# How can I fix an error with loading textures using ImageIO.read [Java] [Beginner]

Tags: java, textures, javax.imageio

I recently decided to try and get back into java after many years away from it and am following a youtube tutorial series for making a game. I have tried to load a texture I made using the following code
(I am using Eclipse)

```
public static Render plane = loadBitmap("/textures/floor.png");

public static Render loadBitmap(String fileName) {
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Texture.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName));
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        Render result = new Render(width, height);
        image.getRGB(0,  0, width, height, result.pixels, 0, width);
        return result;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Debug.logError("CRASH | Failed to load image");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

and I am receiving the following errors:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at net.xernia.bluehero.graphics.Texture.loadBitmap(Texture.java:23)
at net.xernia.bluehero.graphics.Texture.<clinit>(Texture.java:11)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1356)
at net.xernia.bluehero.graphics.Texture.loadBitmap(Texture.java:15)
... 6 more
```

my project structure is as follows:

```
 src
     package
         Texture.java
 res
     textures
         floor.png
```

I have under Properties->java build path added res as a class folder under modulepath. Sorry if this is a very trivial error to some of you, but it is confusing me to no end lol. Hope this is enough information, please let me know if there was something vital I left out :)

Comment: Where is fileName defined and is it null?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but in response to @cam6577, `fileName` is the parameter to the `loadBitmap()` method, it is a String, and in the OPs example, its value is `"/textures/floor.png"`.

Comment: This problem is a *run time* problem. You need to make sure `res` is on class path when you *run* your application, not when you *build* it (ie. it's not "Java build path" that matters. I don't use Eclipse , but something like `java -cp classes/:res/ your.MainClass` should do). Otherwise everything's fine.  You don't need to change or rebuild anything, even though the accepted answer is a viable workaround....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move folder res to src, we have:

```
src
    package
         Texture.java
    res
         textures
             floor.png
```

and change file name to `/res/textures/floor.png`. (Don't forget rebuild project)

Comment: Thanks so much! This fixed it, I've been searching for days lol. Much appreciated :)